# Typecasting base class models in Single Table Inheritence(STI) scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
end  

class Consumer < User 
end  

class Merchant < User 
end   

u = User.find(id)
```

How do I type cast the variable `u` to the type Consumer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a [bug](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2389) in STI, the ActiveRecord finder was returning a base class instance(User) instead of subclass instance(Consumer). I thought this is the default behavior and hence wanted to cast the base class instance(User) to the sub class instance(Consumer). My previous solution became redundant after addressing the bug.
i.e.

```
u = User.find(id) # returns an instance of Consumer class
```

Answer (score 14):

I found the answer to this. The ActiveRecord::Base class has a method for this purpose:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002334

The code will be

```
u = User.find(id)
u = u.becomes(u.type.constantize)
```

Comment: becomes can be used to "fake" that a record is of a given type. As in the doc, this might be useful to use for a subclass.
In your "solution", becomes does nothing useful since u.class == u.type.constantize

Comment: Marc,
  You are right, but my confusion was due to a STI bug. I have explained it in my 2nd answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a column called 'type' and rails will do the rest. For example:

```
id = Consumer.create!(...).id

# later on

User.find(id).is_a? Consumer  # ==> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always get a Consumer as such:

```
u = Consumer.find(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Factory Girl, this is what you want: `create(:consumer).becomes(Consumer)`

Otherwise, `create(:consumer)` only produces a `User` object.